# Is it better to decode a file and read all, or part, of it?

Tags: c#, xml, performance, decode

I have an XML that is entirely encoded in Base64, not just the node text. For some functionality of my program, I only need to  get a couple of nodes from the file. The XML file could contain a couple of hundred nodes, so I'm wondering whether it would be more efficient to decode the file and read the few nodes or to read everything for when (if) it is needed later in the program?

EDIT: When I say, the XML file contain a couple of hundred nodes, there aren't many sub nodes and the file is likely to contain about that number of lines.

UPDATE: Of course though, it is not just about how long it takes! What effect would it have on the memory if I'm storing upwards of 500 strings in the RAM, that may not even be used?

Comment: The correct question is: *do you care at all*? If you are doing this e.g. on response to a user clicking "load XML", going from 500ms to 250ms would be a 50% decrease -- fantastic! But the user is not going to notice, so there would be no point.

Comment: @Jon Are nodes actually read that fast though, an XML file may have 200 - 500 nodes each with two attributes...

Comment: Intuitively I would say that they are much faster than that. But as I said, the first question you have to answer is not "are they fast?" -- it's "do you care?". Is the obvious simple solution good enough for your needs? If it is, move on.

Comment: @Jon - the battery in my phone hates you now.

Comment: @Jon To be fair, I do care somewhat because it's not just me that will be using this program. Other people, with slower computers, will probably be too. Plus, when I wrote this question I was hoping the answers would be useful to others in *similar* situations too.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Why though? Is the phone decoding XML on every tick?

Comment: Why dont you just try it out? How long does it actually take to load the entire file?

Comment: @Andy: This type of question can only be usefully answered in exactly one way: **measure**. But measuring is an involved process and it's meaningless if not done to locate and improve a bottleneck. Most of the time people are using their intuition instead of measuring or even thinking about bottlenecks, which is completely meaningless (blah blah premature optimization blah intuition of even world class developers wrong most of the time blah blah) and the reason I gave this type of canned response. If you want a better response, here it is: **measure**.

Comment: @chris.ellis I asked this question before I started the full implementation, so that I could plan which methods I needed. So, I don't have any real data to test with, however I can get it. It might take me a while, but  I'll do some tests.

Comment: A concrete example: [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/increasing-compiler-speed-by-over-75/240158941) is a very fresh case of a world-class developer who has been writing compilers since forever being somewhat surprised by the performance characteristics of a compiler he wrote himself and has been maintaining for many years. And that's *after* measuring.

Comment: @Jon That's fair enough. I see your point. But what is likely to be the bottleneck here?

Comment: @Andy: The fact that you ask this question makes me skeptical about your having seen the point.

Comment: @Jon - I'm guessing you mean I need to measure in order to find the bottleneck? I understand now.

Comment: @Andy: Yes. Do keep in mind that the first hundred times you attempt to measure something, you are going to do it wrong (like most other disciplines, there are lots of flawed ways to measure and lots to learn on how to avoid the flaws). Also, related blog post by the famous Eric Lippert: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: With regards to your latest update, 500 strings of reasonable length, on a modern machine are completely negligible.

Comment: @chris.ellis Ok, thanks for that. One more question, is it bad practice to keep reading from a file or doesn't it really matter? When I say 'keep reading', I'll only be opening a few input streams (like 10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quite sure there won't be a big diffrence if there are that few nodes in your xml.

But in genreal you could say that it depends on the use case. If you need to work with the nodes a lot it may be more efficient to load all nodes in a faster accessible data container (dictionary for example).

Reason for that is that a Dictionary uses a [HashTable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) to store the data. God thing about a [HashTable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) is that the time complexity is allways O(1) - what compared with the O(n) max complexity of iterating over an xml is allways better.

Comment: I didn't think a couple of hundred was 'that few' nodes. How many nodes would it take to make a difference?

Comment: you should rather talk about lines than nodes (i dont know how many subnodes / attributes you have) - this would give some information about the actual size of your xml.
BTW you wrote "the few nodes" so i inferred that "that few" would match the circumstances

Comment: that is actually quite small ;) noone will notice a diffrence.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. So what file would be large enough to make a difference?

Comment: i would say like 50 mb is quite big for an XML, but heres some reference for XML-Reading performance
https://www.altamiracorp.com/blog/employee-posts/performance-linq-to-sql-vs

Comment: Wow, thanks for the link. What an insight! Is that really under 200 milliseconds for 10, 000 nodes!?

Comment: thats why i called your amounth of nodes "few" ;) but you can test it by yourself - there are plenty of good performance testing frameworks in c#

Comment: I think I will do that. However, please see my edit. Really when I asked about efficiency, I was also talking about the fact I'd be storing all those values in memory...